# [Python ]Using variables defined inside a class (before __init__) in its own methods (__init__, etc.)

Tags: python, list, class, methods, global-variables

I'm trying to make a basket where you can put fruit. The basket is a class, called *basket*, which has an internal list called *contents*. Every time a *basket* fruit instance is created, it's *self.name* property is appended to *contents*. Anyhow, this doesn't work.

```
contents = []

class basket:

## This is where I want to define the list "contents",
## but it doesn't work.

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        global contents
        if name not in contents:
            contents.append(name)
```

For some reason, it only works if I define the list *contents* outside the class altogether, which could affect order and debugging in bigger projects.

Is there any way to make this code work, that lets me define the list *inside* the class? As if to make it a **class-specific "global"variable**, only valid for methods/variables inside the class.

NOTE: The class is supposed to be one basket! Each fruit is called basket by itself, but they are fruit. I want them all inside ONE basket.

Comment: You probably don't want to do that, since then the contents will be shared across all baskets, not specific to each individual basket.  Why don't you do `self.contents = []` inside `__init__`?

Answer (score -1):

This whole answer is just a lengthy explanation about why you shouldn't be doing what you're trying to do...

> *"NOTE: The class is supposed to be one basket! Each fruit is called basket by itself, but they are fruit. I want them all inside ONE basket."*

Before making any attempt to solve that riddle, your actual question must be put in to perspective.

- You're dealing with two nouns - **`Fruit`** and **`Basket`**
- They have an associative relationship: they are independent, but related.

> *"Each fruit is called basket"*

Capital mistake! This is like chessboard and chess pieces. One cannot simply be the other.

> *"I want them all inside ONE basket."*

if by "all" you meant "all fruits", then that could be done.

---

To put things in to perspective, first modify the class names as follows:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now there must be another object called `Basket` to keep track of all the fruits. This doesn't necessarily have to be another class. You can simply make a dictionary, set, list or any other container.

```
basket = set()
```

is a very simple set that can hold all the fruits. Each time when you make a fruit, you can do this to automatically add its name to the basket:

```
basket = set()


class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # This is all that is needed!
        basket.add(name)
```

To test this code:

```
# Making some fruits
for name in ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]:
    Fruit(name)

# Checking the basket
print(basket)
```

The output is as follows:

```
{'Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange'}
```

Now, if you want add more functionality to a `basket` object, you can make in to a class as follows:

```
class Basket(object):
    def __init__(self, fruits=None):
        self.fruits = fruits or set()

    def put(self, fruit):
        """Add a fruit to this basket."""
        self.fruits.add(fruit)

    def show(self):
        """Display all the fruits in this basket."""
        for fruit in self.fruits:
            print(fruit.name) 


class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, basket=None):
        self.name = name

        # Adding it to the basket if needed.
        if basket is not None:
            basket.put(self)



# Making two baskets
gift = Basket()
picnic = Basket()

# Making some fruits and adding them to both baskets
apple = Fruit("Apple", basket=gift)
orange = Fruit("Orange", basket=picnic)
banana = Fruit("Banana", basket=gift)

print("In your gift basket you have:")
gift.show()
print("In your picnic basket you have:")
picnic.show()
```

And this is the output:

```
In your gift basket you have:
Banana
Apple
In your picnic basket you have:
Orange
```